# Генерация ссылок вида sait.com/username

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день! Интересует как генерировать ссылку типа как Вконтакте (т.е. для каждого юзера адрес [vk.com/username,](http://vk.com/username,) а насколько я понимаю шаблон для всех один.) Я конечно же понимаю, что берём из базы: данные и никнейм юзера, выводим эти данные на странице, но вот как этот никнейм вывести в url, или же как впихивать туда каждый раз id пользователя?

**UPD.** Вроде как прочитал что всё это делается с помощью .htaccess, если я правильно прочитал то объясните какой там должен быть код, или дайте линк на статью где это ясно описано.

**UPD2.** Люди, скиньте пожалуйста линк на статью где можно прочитать о таком создании страниц, который описал многоуважаемый **dydydydym**, или же просто объясните толково. Я просто реально не могу понять, как посылать GET запрос для генерации страницы.

Comment: Адреса такого вида часто обрабатываются методом MODEL->VIEW->CONTROL, т.е паттерном MVC...ну это так, на заметку =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Тыщи раз обсуждалось же :)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)$ profile.php?username=$1
```

Comment: Я извиняюсь, просто не нашёл)) А не подскажите, где нужно определять переменую после username? В .htaccess? (я новичок, первый раз работаю с пхп)

Comment: В файле profile.php в передаваемых GET-переменных, то есть $_GET['username'].

Comment: Спасибо большое! Сейчас разберемся.

Comment: Это большой геморой. Например захотим мы что бы регистрация была по адресу: mysite.com/register следовательно нужно исключить возможность регистрации ника: "register" и т.д. Хуже всего, когда мы хотим добавить новую фичу в сайт, на короткий адресс, и такой логин уже есть. Раз у вас возникают вопросы как сделать сабж, то рекомендую не делать так.

Comment: А можете подсказать как называется данная технология. Нигде не могу найти толковый мануал...

Comment: Маршрутизация / роутинг

Comment: А причем тут регистрация? Это уже при самой и регистрации проверяется логин, чтоб он не совпадал с адресом регистрации. А если при добавлении новой фичи такой логин занят, то как-бы уже никак не исправить, как ни крути, только если опять же на стороне регистрации предварительно запретить логины, которые могут в будущем использоваться системой. Начало то всегда одинаковое и оно с htaccess. Где тут геморой? Вопрос был именно про такие профильные урлы.

Comment: dydydydym, сейчас уже главная проблема как формулировать сам запрос.

Comment: 1. Добавили в htaccess эти строки.
2. Заходим на example.com/admin
3. Попадаем на страницу example.com/profile.php?username=admin
4. Выводим на profile.php нужную информацию (берем из базы данных и выводим, 'admin' содержится в переменной $_GET['username'])

Comment: @dydydydym, моё дело предупредить

Comment: @shurik, в чем проблема то? В том, что отсутствует пункт "сравниваем username с глобально-нужными именами"? Если прописать в htaccess заранее

    RewriteRule ^register$ index.php?act=register
А потом реврайт на profile.php - все прекрасно сработает и по урлу /register мы попадем на index.php?act=register. И то, как я уже написал, про регистрацию здесь речи не шло.

Comment: @shurik, а можно вообще не выёживаться, и юзеров держать по урлам типа /users/name (как, например, в тех же фотках или видео на Яндексе). И все остальные адреса будут явно отделены от пользовательских. Ничто, кроме понтов, от этого не пострадает :) Или наоборот, для служебных адресов завести отдельный префикс. В общем, проблема притянута за уши.